# Angular- When I click on a component, all instances of that component are reinitalized

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

There is a page of project cards. Each card has a favorite button. If the project is not in favorites, it will become a favorite when the button is clicked. There is an icon in the project-card that changes according to whether the project is a favorite or not.

The problem is when I click the favorite button, all project-card components are reinitalized and favorite icon doesn't change. The following code will help more.

project-carousel.component.html

```
<app-project-card *ngFor="let project of projects" [project]="project" [isFavorite]="isFavorite(project.id)"></app-project-card>
```

project-card.component.html

```
<div class="project-fav-btn" (click)="favorite()">
     <i [ngClass]="{'fas':isFavorite, 'far':!isFavorite}" class="fa-heart"></i>
</div>
```

project-card.component.ts

```
export class ProjectCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() project: Proje;
  @Input() isFavorite: boolean;

  constructor(private favoriteService: FavoriteService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  favorite(): void {
    if (this.isFavorite) {
      this.favoriteService.deleteFavorite(this.project.id);
    } else {
      this.favoriteService.addFavorite(this.project.id);
    }
    this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
  }
}
```

So what I want to do is; When I click on the favorite button, I want to add that project to favorites and change the favorite icon.
I am waiting for your suggestions for a solution or a different approach.

Comment: my guess is you have a flaw in your projects subscription. If you reload the entire projects when a change occurs and replace the current projects you are working with with a new set of projects, this might come from here. Try to see how your logic works.

Comment: can you share more code I am wondering something is wrong in isFavorite(project.id). ?

Comment: The "clasic" solution is that "isFavorite" was a property of your `Proje` and not use the `@Input() isFavorite` and the variable of the component `ìsFavorite` else `this.project.isFavorite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **trackBy** with your ngfor. this will probably solve this kind of issues you are facing.

check angular doc for implementation https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

or try below code,

```
<app-project-card *ngFor="let project of projects; trackBy:trackByProjectId" [project]="project" [isFavorite]="isFavorite(project.id)" ></app-project-card>
```

in component.ts

```
trackByProjectId(index: number, project: any): string {  
    return project.id;  // need to return unique key from your project , you can adjust this one 

  }
```